# Fancybox youtube

Tags: youtube, fancybox

I am trying to get a fancybox YouTube video to start about 12 minutes into a video. Can someone help me with achieving this? No matter what I have tried, since I am a novice, I cannot get the video to start where I want it to.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have already managed to display the video in fancybox and you just you want to select the start time at 12 minutes, don't you?

If so, in the URL of the youtube video just add at the end `#t=12m00s` (time in minutes and seconds) like

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaFVr_cJJIY#t=12m00s
```

you could also use this format

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/JaFVr_cJJIY&autoplay=1#t=12m00s
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the latest version of Fancybox (2+), YouTube and Vimeo are now recognized and handled quite well.

However, it took some digging around to find this out since most documentation is on Fancybox 1.

Fancybox strips your YouTube URL and adds some default parameters:

- **autoplay=1** (videos will autoplay)
- **autohide=1** (control will hide once video is playing)
- **fs=1** (fullscreen is enabled)
- **rel=0** (related videos are hidden)
- **hd=1** (HD playback is enabled)
- **wmode=opaque** (fixes z-index with YouTube and lightboxes)
- **enablejsapi=1** (enables Javascript API)

What this means that normally you could pass those parameters in your URL and have them apply, but Fancybox 2 ignores those and falls back on the preset values.

Don't dismay!  You can override those in your script.  Several ways.

**Normal media embed:**

```
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      helpers : {
          media: true
      }
  });
```

**Custom URL parameters method 1:**

```
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      helpers : {
          media: {
              youtube : {
                  params : {
                      autoplay : 0
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  });
```

**Custom URL parameters method 2:**

```
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({,
       helpers : {
          media: true
      },
      youtube : {
          autoplay: 0
      }
  });
```

For your issue, you want to pass in this parameter:

$(".fancybox").fancybox({,
           helpers : {
              media: true
          },
          youtube : {
              start: 720 
          }
      });